# PHP Echo and Includes

Tags: php

When I use the following PHP code:

`$id = $_GET['page'];  $page = include ($id.'.php');  echo $page;`

The code within the $id.php file is returned, however there is a "1" appended to it, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please clarify - are you actually using a `return` call at the end of the included file to store the return value into `$page`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, example 5

Comment: Note also, this could be vulnerable to file inclusion attacks or null-byte injection. Be sure to filter against `..` and `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include()` will return boolean TRUE if the file was successfully included. You then echo out that true value, which is printed as a `1`.

Of note: never directly use user-provided data ($_GET['page']) in file system operations. It's a hideious security risk. You've at least got `.php` being appended so it's not quite as large a gaping hole, but still... don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

- You shouldn't echo a page like that.

  `include()` is used to import the document onto your current working file.
- By using `$page = include ($id.'.php');`, you are assigning boolean value to `$page`

  This will hold the success status of the `include()` statement

  - If the page load successfully, it give true, whose numeric value is `1`
  - If the load was unsuccessfully, it gives false, whose numeric value is `0`

---

However, the way you are using is not entirely incorrect

For example: Create a page `Test.php` to return a value at the end

> $t = "some text"; 
>      return $t;

Then you will able to use it to echo

```
echo include("test.php"); //outputs "some text"
```

---

I suggest you tead the [documenation](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for complete guide

Comment: `include()` can also be used to `return` a value  and assign it. This is valid code, albeit possibly misguided

Comment: @Michael, yeah, but only if the included page returns a value. I think i should include this in the answer

Comment: And do we know the OP is _not_ returning a value without seeing the included code? No. That's why I asked for clarification from the OP.

Comment: @Michael, I think my answer should be complete now

Answer (score 1):

because the 1 is the return code of the [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), which you are saving in the $page variable.

The code within $id.php is returned when you do the include(), the only thing your 'echo' is printing is the 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes! When you `include`, you're just telling PHP to parse the additional file as well. The variable you've set--`$page`-- just contains the return value of the `include()` function. Since it's 1, I'd say you included the other file successfully.

On a related note, it's generally (meaning, almost never) a good idea to include an arbitrary file based on un-parsed parameters from a user request. By manipulating the value of `page` passed to your script, a theoretical attacker could get your machine to execute any PHP file in the system--a dangerous proposition!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because include will return true or false (0 or 1). Actually you include the page content and then echo $page. This will print "1".

Hope you got it. Don't echo $page at the end. Just use include.